# Instagram official public_content API vs unofficial JSON API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

It seems that Instagram has two means of scraping public data. There is the official API for which you need to get an API key and permissions, as described in the guide https://www.instagram.com/developer/   For a tag-specific search, the official API uses the endpoint:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

But it also seems that many people are scraping Instagram by using a different public API (which I think is the one accessed by the front-end of the website). This "unofficial" API uses the endpoint:

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{tag-name}/?__a=1
```

I cannot find any information regarding support for the "unofficial" version. Does anybody know what limitations may exist on this API? If this method of retrieving data satisfies the requirements of our application, is there any reason we should still engage the rigorous API token review process to get our application approved for "official" API public_content permissions?

Comment: Any progress? Thanks for deep details.

Comment: Haven't found an answer to this but my guess is that one is "officially" supported while the other is just a hack on the front page of the website. There might also be some differences when it comes to users' non-public pages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know

> Does anybody know what limitations may exist on this API?

- It is a direct violation of Instagram terms of use as in [here](https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511#)

  > 10.We prohibit crawling, scraping, caching or otherwise accessing any content on the Service via automated means, including but not
  >   limited
  >   to, user profiles and photos (except as may be the result of standard
  >   search engine protocols or technologies used by a search engine with
  >   Instagram's express consent).
- And as a developer there is no grantee that these API remain
  unchanged. so you probably experiencing system fail and be forced to
  re develop parts of your code times to time.
- Also it worth mentioning that users won't easily give you username
  and passwords of their account, as the public API just requires
  confirmation to access limited account resources.

> is there any reason we should still engage the rigorous API token
>   review process to get our application approved for "official" API
>   public_content permissions?

- Same as a bow